# Why doesn't my Python socket correctly send data but my serial terminal does?

Tags: python, serial-port, embedded, pyserial

I have to send some serial commands from a PC to an equipment as part of a bigger application and no matter what i try, i cannot seem to get python to send the data correctly. When i send the same commands through Termite, everything works as expected. I've been trying to solve this for days and i'm at a loss as to what i could try next.

The things i did and could rule out as not the cause for this issue:

1. Improper socket configuration: I've made sure to use the correct baud rate, bitlength, parity and stopbits as Termite (which happen to be the default settings for the socket anyways)
2. Check the command's correctness and termination: Within Termite i have to append `CRLF` as termination, so in Python i just add `\r\n` at the end of the command. This seems to be identical, as i've checked both commands on the oscilloscope and they are identical, termination characters included. I've went further and also used a serial port monitor and compared the two and they're identical - no missing bits and correct termination.
3. I've tried adding a heading `\r\n` to each command (this is what the equipment expects as command termination) thinking there might be some garbage or noise when first sending some data, but to no avail.
4. Clearing the input buffer, maybe there could be some issue when not reading from a socket that sends some response. I dont need what the equipment sends via serial, it offers no useful feedback but i did this anyways and have gotten no results. Before each transmission, i make sure to read all the bytes available.
5. Making sure Windows does not close my port. This i'm not that sure of, maybe it still does it after some long time, but so far i've gotten no errors and could always write and receive data, as confirmed by the serial monitor.

Below are some excerpts of socket configuration and command sending:

```
try:
    self.SPC = serial.Serial(port=connectionData.get("spc_com"), baudrate=115200, timeout=1)
except serial.SerialException as err:
    print(f'SPC Serial Error: {err.strerror}')
    return False

def SPCCommand(self, command: str):
    if not command:
        return

    try:
        self.readAndClearBuffer()
        self.SPC.write(command.encode())
    except serial.SerialException as err:
        print(f'SPC Serial Error: {err.strerror}')
        return

def readAndClearBuffer(self):
    data = ''

    while True:
        try:
            data = self.SPC.read(1024)

            if not data:
                return

            print(data)
        except serial.SerialException as err:
            return

self.SPCCommand("\r\n8000011200000000")
```

I don't have any idea what else to try. The fact that the commands are identical on the oscilloscope, as well as the serial monitor, leaves me at a loss. Could there be a different issue? Is there anything else i could try?

Comment: "*i cannot seem to get python to send the data correctly*" -- That is your conclusion, rather than a description of something you actually observed.  What actually happens that is not expected?  (That means do not list what does *not* happen.)  IOW what happens that makes you "conclude" that there is a problem "with sending"?

Comment: @sawdust the thing that makes me conclude that there might be a problem with sending data via python is that the equipment does not respond to any command. I cannot debug the equipment and have no access to what exactly reaches the target serial port, but i can get it working via serial terminal, thus i can concur that the equipment is working correctly and so is the serial terminal. The only thing that doesn't work is python code i wrote. I don't know what else i could say to shed more light on the issue, but i can provide any details should they be needed.

Comment: "*the equipment does not respond to any command*" -- You persist in making ambiguous summations.  What is a "*response*"?  Are you expecting a message in return?  Is the device supposed to visibly change its state?  Your words sounds good, but you only provide generalizations.  There are no details or specifics.  "*i can provide any details*" -- Perhaps you can start by identifying this mystery "*equipment*"?  What are the physical connections?  Describe one command, and one result.

Comment: The device is an electric motor that communicates via rs232. If i send a start command, it should start turning. If i send a stop command, it should stop. It does neither when i send the strings using python and does both of them correctly when send them via serial terminal. The motors sends some messages when powered, but they are useles and it does not provide any feedback when turning or stopping.

Comment: "*The device is an electric motor that communicates via rs232.*" -- Have you reviewed the signals of this device's RS-232 connector?  Are there any handshake or flow-control signals?